# Change CJK fonts in default fontset

Tags: fonts

Is there a way to change the CJK fonts used in the default fontset?  Currently, when I open the HELLO file using <kbd>C-h h</kbd>, I see:

- `Japanese (日本語)   こんにちは / ｺﾝﾆﾁﾊ` with charset `japanese-jisx0208` and font `mac-ct:-*-Hiragino Sans-normal-normal-normal-*-16-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1`;
- `Chinese (中文,普通话,汉语)  你好` with charset `chinese-gb2312` and font `mac-ct:-*-PingFang SC-normal-normal-normal-*-16-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1`;
- `Cantonese (粵語,廣東話)   早晨, 你好` with charset `chinese-big5-1` and font `mac-ct:-*-PingFang TC-normal-normal-normal-*-16-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1`; and
- `Korean (한글)  안녕하세요 / 안녕하십니까` with charset `korean-ksc5601` and font `mac-ct:-*-Apple SD Gothic Neo-normal-normal-normal-*-16-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1`.

Let’s say I wanted to use the Noto Sans Mono CJK fonts instead of the macOS defaults.  Evaluating

```
(set-fontset-font "fontset-startup" 'chinese-big5-1
                  (font-spec :family "Noto Sans Mono CJK TC") nil t)
```

causes *both* Chinese and Cantonese to use it, while I would like only Cantonese to use Traditional Chinese.  (Likewise with `chinese-gb2312` and Simplified Chinese.)

I could not figure out how the default fontset is configured to cleanly differentiate Japanese, Simplified Chinese, Traditional Chinese, and Korean.